# Provide alternative to image datatype in sqlserver

Tags: c#, android

Please help finding a solutions to this problem. I have an image string encoded in base64 in sql server database by using  this function in c#

```cs
public string ImageToBase64()   
{  
    string path = "D:\\SampleImage.jpg";  
    using(System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path))  
    {  
        using(MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())  
        {  
            image.Save(m, image.RawFormat);  
            byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();  
            base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);  
            return base64String;  
        }  
    }  
}
```

i use this code to retrieve the image data in android

```
Byte[] imageBytes = Base64.decode(rs.getstring("imagedata"), Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length); 
imageView.setImageBitmap(decodedImage);
```

The following error shows in log :

> D/skia: --- Failed to create image decoder with message
> 'unimplemented'

Please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i find the answer,

Just don't use any encoding technics while converting image to and from image datatype .. Both while inserting to sql server and getting data from db.

Thanks !!

Comment: note: the `image` type in SQL Server has been obsolete for something like a decade? `varbinary(max)` is usually preferred; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql

Comment: Yes , but its an old db & have lots of data. Our c# development team don't want to change it. Any way they are storing data as byte [ ] -_-